# Node.js - Nginx 502

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, nginx

I'm getting a 502 error in my production environment, but not on my local install of my app, for a certain route. I've narrowed the problem down to the callback of the `.aggregate()` method that I'm querying the database with.

This is the callback:

```
    function(err,f){
        var f = f[0].forms;

        if(err) console.log(err);
        if (callback) {
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/javascript');
            res.send(callback + '(' + JSON.stringify(f) + ')');
        } else {
            res.end("Callback not set");
        }
    }
```

It works for my local install. I'm using this callback to send the object to another source using jsonp. Is there something I'm not doing correctly?

Answer (score 0):

If you're logging an error, probably best to not continue to the next line of code.

```
if(err) {
  console.log(err);
  return done(err); //or send the error page, or do something other than continue on.
}
```

Can you see more contents of the error message?

Comment: I can't see anything that comes out of that. I checked the nginx logs and this error is present: `2015/02/03 07:31:38 [error] 6342#0: *3 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: xx.xxx.xx.xxx, server: , request: "GET /form?callback=processJSON HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/form?callback=processJSON", host: "api.example.com"`

Comment: I'm not using Unicorn. I am certain that my problem has something to do with the callback that I posted.